# Normal Compact Operator: not diagonalizable!

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

To proposition 5.17 in Weidmann's 'Lineare Operatoren in Hilberträumen' (german version) it is noted that the expansion of compact operators that are normal rather than self adjoint doesn't apply in general for real Hilbert spaces.

Can you give an example where the expansion fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is given by: 
$$\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$$

What fails there is that despite being normal (and compact of course) it has no(!) eigenvectors at all. Therefore it cannot be diagonalizable.

Comment: The matrix is not diagonalizable only if you restrict yourself only to real numbers. You can diagonalize it with complex numbers.

Comment: Yes I know but the question concerns the situation when complex Hilbert space is replaced by real Hilbert space ;)

Comment: sorry I missed the word 'real' in original question

Comment: You're welcome ;)